# Using system() function in c

Tags: c, linux, windows, system

I want to use the system function to get the number of accounts on windows and on linux.
I have no idea where to look. Please just point me in the right direction.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please read the [FAQ] before too long.  What have you tried?  What constitutes an account?  Where do you look for information about accounts on Linux?  Where do you look for information about accounts on Windows?  What command would you run from the shell, because that's the command you'll run via `system()`?  If you don't know the way to do it at the shell (CMD window prompt) you're on a hiding to nothing.  Research that first; when you can get the answer outside your C code, getting it with `system()` inside your C code is child's play.

Answer (score 0):

The `system()` function runs a program.  If you know a command line that does what you need, you can use `system()` to run that command line.

I'm not sure what command-line program would give the number of accounts on Windows.  You could get an approximation by looking at the number of home directories.  On Windows the home directories are in `\Users` and on Linux home directories are in `/home'.

The `system()` function doesn't capture the output of the program.  You would then likely need to run a command line that redirects the program output to a file, then open this file and parse the output.

You would probably have an easier time solving this problem using a language like Python.  Python programs are very portable and there are some wrappers for system stuff.

Good luck.

Comment: "Python programs are very portable"... How many Sega Megadrives do you know that'll run a Python implementation?

Comment: @modifiablelvalue, how many Sega Megadrives do you know that run Windows or Linux?

Comment: That is an irrelevant indication of the portability of Windows or Linux, not the portability of Python programs.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know in Linux, but on windows:

[NetUserEnum()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370652%28VS.85%29.aspx) or [NetQueryDisplayInformation()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370610%28VS.85%29.aspx) and ofcourse from the Registry here: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList`

PS: `system(const char *command)` function call executes the `command` in the command window/terminal.

Answer (score 0):

I used Google to find the following:

Windows:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vcgeneral/thread/8c72b948-d32c-4785-930e-0d6fdf032ecc

Linux:
http://www.linuxforums.org/forum/miscellaneous/29508-list-all-user-accounts-system.html

*(search strings: "win32 get user account information", "linux get user account information")*

The Linux page gives a command line, so you can put that in your `system()` call. In Windows though, you don't use `system()`, you use Win32 API.

Answer (score 0):

For Linux systems you might like to count the number of lines in the file `/etc/passwd`. This file contains an entry for each user to the system.

To count lines of a text file under Linux the `wc` command can be used.

Anyway, if you need this info in a C program I propose you take a different approach:

You could open a text file using `fopen()` and read each line using `fgets()` until `fgets()` tells you there are no more lines. Doing so you'll be getting the number of users.