# Trying to use 'system()' and 'execv()' function calls

Tags: c, linux, unix, exec

I want to execute a C program from another C program. **Actually I need to use `system()` function for my functionality as the control returns to the calling program**. As I was not able to get the result with `system()`, I tried using `execv()` which was not successful either.

Below are the sample codes which I was trying

```
int main(void) {
puts("executing this prog from another prog"); 
return EXIT_SUCCESS; 
}
```

The above one is called test1.c

```
int main(void) {
execv("./test1",NULL); //system("./test1");
puts("!!!Hello World!!!"); 
return EXIT_SUCCESS; 
}
```

This is test2.c

With `system()`, I am getting the `sh: 1: ./test1: not found` error and with `execv()` its just ignoring the statement and printing the `!!!Hello World!!!`

Note : Mainly I want to know the functioning of `system()` for the problem I want to solve.

Comment: The error you get from `system` should be a very good hint about the problem.

Comment: Did you compile `test1.c` into `test1`?

Comment: Is the `test1` executable in your current working directory?

Comment: `system()` is not a system call, I removed that tag.

Comment: `NULL` is not a valid second argument to `execv()`. It requires a valid `argv` array there.

Comment: @Barmar yes `test1` is executable and its in the current directory

Comment: If you want to use `execv()` and also continue the original program, you need to use `fork()` to run it in a child process.

Comment: @Barmar Instead of having both `execv()` and `fork()`, I can use `system()`. Right ?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. And it should have worked if the path is correct.

Comment: @Barmar I have tried even with the array argument. `char *arr[] = {"./test1",NULL};
 execv(arr[0],arr);`

Comment: if `execv()` returns it's because it got an error, you should use `perror()` to see the reason.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [System Call fork() and execv function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19147386/608639), [How to use execv system call in linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32142164/608639), [What is the difference between the functions of the exec family of system calls like exec and execve?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20823371/608639), [System call vs Function call](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2668747/608639), [Using system() function in c](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15079921/608639), etc

Comment: @karra Try to use `access()` before `system()` to check if your file exists and if it has execute permission: https://linux.die.net/man/2/access

Comment: When I have used `echo $?` it returned number 127 and in `man` page it says that if `\bin\sh` could not be executed it returns the 127 number.

Comment: I have provided execution permission for the file. I have gone through the previous questions posted in stack overflow. I don't know what I am missing.

Comment: Can you change `system("./test1");` to `system("pwd; ls -ld ./test1");` and see if the output is what you expect for the current directory name and the file?

Comment: If you are after the output written to `stdout` using `popen()` would be another option.

Answer (score 0):

The second parameter of `execv` must be an array of pointers to null-terminated strings, change to:

```
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void)
{
    char *argv[] = {NULL};
    execv("./test1", argv);
    return 0;
}
```

If this fails you can check the cause of the error with `perror`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void)
{
    char *argv[] = {NULL};
    if (execv("./test1", argv) == -1) {
        perror("execv");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    return 0;
}
```